# How to connect a list to nodes to a single node in Python networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

In this problem, I have 1000 nodes that I want to connect to a single big node using the Python Networkx library functions. Normally, to connect a list of nodes to a single node, we write the following code:

```
    H.add_edges_from([('N','1'),('N','2'),('N','3'),('N','5'),('N','6'), ('N','7')])
```

Where, N is the major node and 1-7 are the nodes that are connected to it. For 1000 nodes however, this process seems infeasible. I have been writing a code for this and it is like this:

```
    for i in range(1001):
        H.add_edges_from[('N',i)]
```

But this generates the error, TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable.

In such a case, how can i connect a bunch of nodes to a single node?

Comment: You misse parenthesis `H.add_edges_from([('N',i)])`

Comment: You can also do `H.add_edges_from([('N',i) for i in range(1001)])` to call the method once with all the nodes